# Chaining multiple $http.get() ng-init angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

Im working on a scenario where on page load i have 2 `$http.get()` request. One `$http.get()` are independent on another `$http.get()`. Every thing works fine.But in some situation my 2nd `$http.get()` request executes before the 1st `$http.get()` and i'm not able to get the desired output. How can we chain the request? Since i'm new to AngularJS i don't have that much idea.

```js
$scope.onload = function()
{
    var responsePromise1 = $http.get(1st rest call);
    responsePromise1.success(function(data) { 

        console.log(data.platform.record);
        $scope.records=data.platform.record;
    });

    responsePromise1.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("ajax failed");
    });

    var responsePromise2 = $http.get(2nd rest call);
    responsePromise2.success(function(data2) {
        console.log(data2.platform.record);
        $scope.records2=data2.platform.record;
    });

    responsePromise2.error(function(data2, status, headers, config) {
        alert("ajax failed");
    });
}
$scope.butto = function(datafrom1st,datafrom2nd)
{
    var responsePromise3 = $http.get(3rd rest call);
    responsePromise3.success(function(data3) { 
        console.log(data3.platform.record);
        $scope.records3=data3.platform.record;
    });

    responsePromise1.error(function(data3, status, headers, config) {
        alert("ajax failed");
    });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div ng-init="onload()">
    <div ng-repeat="record in records">
      {{record.id}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="record2 in records2">
      {{record2.name}}
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-cloak"
            style="padding-bottom:25px;font-weight:bold;" 
            ng-init="butto(record.id,record2.name)">
      {{record3.data}}
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `responsePromise1` execute before `responsePromise2` but they are both asynchronize call, which mean we can not guarantee who will finish first.

If you need to chain the request ,your  `responsePromise2` must be inside the `sucess` of `responsePromise1`

Comment: If they're independent you shouldn't chain them.

Comment: If they are independent of each other use a Promise All. In the 'then' callback, it will have both responses.

Comment: Use controllers instead of `ng-init` and use services to call APIs. Post your html and routes for a better answer

Comment: See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises). Also see [SO: Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Promise.all, if they are independent of each other. But you need to execute the code in a specific order.

```
var responsePromise1 = $http.get(1st rest call);
var responsePromise2 = $http.get(2nd rest call);
var promises = [responsePromise1,responsePromise2]

// Array of Promises
$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(data){
         var data1 = data[0];
         var data2 = data[1];
         // Put logic here to handle both responses.
         return $http.get(3rd rest call);
     })
     .then(function(data3){
         // Put logic here to handle third response
     });
```

Comment: can you explain more about $q.all(promises)

Comment: `$q.all([])` returns a promise that resolves when all promises passed to it, have resolved. So in this case the function in `then` is called, when both `responsePromise1` and `responsePromise2` have resolved successfully. If any one of the passed promises fails/is rejected, the `$q.all` is immediately rejected as well. If `responsePromise1` and `responsePromise2` are truly independent, I'm not sure this is what you want, since if one fails, the other fails as well.

Comment: bro i have 3 $http.get() . i want the output of 1st two to pass in the 3rd request

Comment: You should include that in your original question then. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: how can i achieve it bro. im stuck at this place

Comment: @dockerr for the third request, just put it in after the first two resolves in the promise.all.

Comment: do you have a demo. Since im new to angularjs i dont have that much idea

Comment: @dockerrrr no, i do not have a demo. Why don't you try to create a demo and we can look at what you tried instead?

Answer (score 0):

Call 2nd request inside success method of 1st request:

```
var responsePromise1 = $http.get(1st rest call);
        responsePromise1.success(function(data)
        { 
          console.log(data.platform.record);
          $scope.records=data.platform.record;
var responsePromise2 = $http.get(2nd rest call);
        responsePromise2.success(function(data2)
        {
        console.log(data2.platform.record);
        $scope.records2=data2.platform.record;
        });
        responsePromise2.error(function(data2, status, headers, config)
        {
          alert("ajax 2 failed");
        });
        });
        responsePromise1.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {alert("ajax failed");
        });
```

Comment: bro but im using 2 ng-init.One when for the 1st request and other for the second request

Comment: what's you mean ?

Comment: i'm having 2 different functions.

Comment: I think you should add 2nd init inside success method, in this case this async method, so you need call 2nd when 1st success.

Comment: is there any problem in adding a ng-init function inside success method .Whether it gets executed?

Comment: it wont get executed

Answer (score 0):

The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service.

```
$http
  .get(1st rest call)
  .then(function(data){
       $scope.records = data.platform.record;
       return $http.get(2nd rest call);
  })
  .then(function(result){
     //result of 2nd rest call
  })
  .catch(function(err){
     // Here catch error
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
   $scope.onload = function()
    {
    var responsePromise1 = $http.get(1st rest call);
        responsePromise1.success(function(data) { 
    SecondInit()
        console.log(data.platform.record);
            $scope.records=data.platform.record;
        });

        responsePromise1.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("ajax failed");
        });


      }
    function SecondInit(){
    var responsePromise2 = $http.get(2nd rest call);
        responsePromise2.success(function(data2) {
            console.log(data2.platform.record);
            $scope.records2=data2.platform.record;
        });

        responsePromise2.error(function(data2, status, headers, config) {
            alert("ajax failed");
        });
```

Here i am trying to bind  the second api call to function named SecondInit() and invoke in it on success of first api call this might help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, using `$q.all` as per Hoyen's suggestion:

```
$scope.onload = function(){

    var promise1 = $http.get('/request1');
    var promise2 = $http.get('/request2');

    $q.all([ promise1, promise2 ]).then(function(data){
        var response1 = data[0].platform.record;
        var response2 = data[1].platform.record;

        $scope.records = response1.map(function(e, i){
            var id = e.id;
            var name = response2[i].name;
            return {id: id, name: name};
        });
    });
};
```

Then in your view, do this:

```
<body>
    <div ng-init="onload()">
        <div ng-repeat="record in records">
            <div>{{record.id}}</div>
            <div>{{record.name}}</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-cloak" style="padding-bottom:25px;font-weight:bold;" 
                ng-click="butto(record.id,record.name)"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This should work, but I would really recommend you find a good up-to-date angular tutorial and read up on best practices. This isn't really the optimal way to solve this kind of problem.